# How do I use BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory to store BigDecimals using Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I need to store a currency value (not indexed) in my entity and I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: kmrate: java.math.BigDecimal is not a supported property type.
```

Googling around, it seems that BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory might be part of the solution, but I can't find any documentation or examples for it.

Comment: Did you install the converter as described in docs? http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory.html

Comment: By install, you mean invoke "ObjectifyService.factory().getTranslators().add(new BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory());" ?  Yes I did that

Comment: In my code I have ObjectifyService.factory().getTranslators().add(new BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory(100000));, which seems to work fine (using 4.0rc1). Are you sure you haven't called ObjectifyService.setFactory(anotherFactory); afterwards anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yep, sure. I suspect my problem is that I have no idea how to use/annotate/invoke the Translator.

So I can move forward, for now I've simply changed the attribute definition from BigDecimal to String and modified my getters and setters to do a conversion.

Comment: If you have the BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory installed, you can just use BigDecimal as-is; Objectify will recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory() say to install it "at the same time you perform registration", but I found that it must be BEFORE registration.

Eg, using the recommended ["Use Your Own Service"](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices#Use_Your_Own_Service) approach for registering entities, the following will cause a later save() of an entity containing BigDecimal properties to fail with an UnsupportedOperationException (with message "Unsupported data type: java.math.BigDecimal"):

```
public class OfyService {
    static {
        factory().register(Thing.class);
        factory().register(OtherThing.class);
        factory().getTranslators().add(new BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory());
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }
    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

But it works if I do it before registration:

```
public class OfyService {
    static {
        factory().getTranslators().add(new BigDecimalLongTranslatorFactory());
        factory().register(Thing.class);
        factory().register(OtherThing.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }
    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

I haven't dug into Objectify's translator system to see exactly why this might be.

Note: I'm using Objectify 4.0b3.